# Multithreading frozen in Python Spyder but not command prompt Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, spyder

I am running a script inside Spyder that utilizes the multithreading library and the IPython console freezes with the output below. However, running the script using Windows command prompt via 'python quickstart11.py' works fine and generates the proper output.

```
    runfile('C:/Python35/User/backtrader-master/docs/quickstart/quickstart11.py', wdir='C:/Python35/User/backtrader-master/docs/quickstart')
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 429, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'TestStrategy' on <module '__main__' (<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000002727C461438>)>
```

I've tried adding freeze_support() according to [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support), which should alleviate the problem, but it still freezes. What is going on?

Windows 10 64bit, Anaconda Python 35 64bit installer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Spyder. The kernel is running in interpreted mode and the addition of "freeze_support" doesn't happend before other things even if that's the intention, because the kernel is already running.

See here: https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/issues/118